# Hibernate hbm subclass

Tags: hibernate

I have this hbm:

```
<class name="Payment" table="PAYMENT">
<id name="id" type="long" column="PAYMENT_ID">
    <generator class="native"/>
</id>

<property name="amount" column="AMOUNT"/>
...
<subclass name="CreditCardPayment" >
    <join table="CREDIT_PAYMENT">
        <property name="creditCardType" column="CCTYPE"/>
        ...
    </join>
</subclass>
```

I don't wanna use the tag  `<discriminator>`
And I wanna get 2 concrete tables , one for "Payment" and one for "CreditCardPayment"
is that HBM satisfies my need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to use `<subclass>` approach, [then you'll need a **discriminator**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass). That happens because [hibernate allows mixing subclass strategies with that tag](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-mixing-tableperclass-tablepersubclass), so you can have different type of entities in a single table, some of them which are required to perform a join operation and others that have all their values stored in that main table. Here you have the `CreditCardPayment` which needs a join and the other type of payments which are simpler:

```
<class name="Payment" table="PAYMENT">
    <id name="id" type="long" column="PAYMENT_ID">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <discriminator column="PAYMENT_TYPE" type="string"/>
    <property name="amount" column="AMOUNT"/>
    ...
    <subclass name="CreditCardPayment" discriminator-value="CREDIT">
        <join table="CREDIT_PAYMENT">
            <property name="creditCardType" column="CCTYPE"/>
            ...
        </join>
    </subclass>
    <subclass name="CashPayment" discriminator-value="CASH">
        ...
    </subclass>
    <subclass name="ChequePayment" discriminator-value="CHEQUE">
        ...
    </subclass>
</class>
```

You can however specify `<joined-subclass>`, which is equivalent to what you're doing and then hibernate will do a join and get the elements for each class without a discriminator. Keep in mind you **can't mix** `<subclass>` and `<joined-subclass>` elements in the same class.

Here you have the **table-per-subclass** implementation which doesn't need discriminator, it forces you to use a single table per concrete class implementation, but you can manage parent entities of the `Payment` class as well.

```
<class name="Payment" table="PAYMENT">
    <id name="id" type="long" column="PAYMENT_ID">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="amount" column="AMOUNT"/>
    ...
    <joined-subclass name="CreditCardPayment" table="CREDIT_PAYMENT">
        <key column="PAYMENT_ID"/>
        <property name="creditCardType" column="CCTYPE"/>
        ...
    </joined-subclass>
    <joined-subclass name="CashPayment" table="CASH_PAYMENT">
        <key column="PAYMENT_ID"/>
        ...
    </joined-subclass>
    <joined-subclass name="ChequePayment" table="CHEQUE_PAYMENT">
        <key column="PAYMENT_ID"/>
        ...
    </joined-subclass>
</class>
```

Comment: Biker, another question :)
I have extra code in the super class defined in the tag  <meta attribute="class-code">, I get the same code in the subclass!
How it can be only for the super one?

Comment: You can specify `meta` tags into subclasses, just override what you want

Comment: and how can I define an id for the subclass?